# Layouting images with circular dependencies

Tags: android

There shall be two images r and l and another view M aligned like this.
`llMMMMMMrr`
`llMMMMMMrr`

(Explanation of the above. l and r are two units wide and high, M is two units high and fills the remaining space)

Edit: added an image how this should look like

[image]

M has a defined height.
l and r shall share M's height and be square shaped, that means their size depends on M's height. This already is a problem, how to make an image set it's x dimension to the y dimension that comes from somewhere outside?

Then how to accomplish the positioning and size?
I tried different layouts (linear, relative) and positioning of the images but I always end up with at least a circular dependency that the designer in AndroidStudio can resolve but the build process can't.

For example in a RelativeLayout if l and r appear first in the layout xml then M knows where to be (between r and l). But r and l can't top-align and bottom-align to M because M is unknown to them.
If M appears first then l and r know how tall to be but M has no idea where to be because l and r aren't known.

I think I am making a fundamental error here or I'm missing a very different way to solve this.
What is the best way to position my elements as described?

Comment: would you provide any sample screenshot for better understanding ?

Comment: Perhaps the downvoters could at least provide an improvement or find something else to show their coolness? I think this is a reasonable question and I searched a lot without finding a clue.

Comment: @Droidum Probably by creating custom views can resolve your problem.  Check out this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_components.htm  . Now based on the middle component height, you can create other two. And align accordingly

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your problem [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) can solve your problem. Use `ConstraintLayout`. It has many features to design complex layout and its a flat view hierarchy.

For your requirement you have to use `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` for dimension ration of the ImageView.It will control `ImageView` height and weight ration.  And also need to set top and bottom constraint with `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` property for the ImageView.

And finally use `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` constraint to take the remaining space between the ImageViews

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:minWidth="5dp"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Screen shot

[image]

- `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` will always keep ImageView width and height ration 1:1.
- `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"` this both constraint will keep `ImageView` height same as `EditText`. and `ImageView` Dimension Ratio constraint will make width same as height.
- `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"` and `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"`constraint will make `EditText` to take remaining space between `ImageView`.

Makesure your `EditText` `layout_width` property set to `0dp` else it will not use start and end constraint and it will not resize dynamically. `0dp` means `match_constraint`.

To learn about ConstraintLayout check [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)